# Пустой вывод при парсинге XML

Tags: php, html, xml

Пытаюсь вывести значение "НаименованиеПолное", но получаю пустой вывод, что я делаю не так?

```
<?php
    //OPEN
$xml = simplexml_load_file("2.xml");

var_dump($xml=>Номенклатура->НаименованиеПолное);

?>
```

XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<V8Exch:_1CV8DtUD xmlns:V8Exch="http://www.1c.ru/V8/1CV8DtUD/" xmlns:core="http://v8.1c.ru/data" xmlns:v8="http://v8.1c.ru/8.1/data/enterprise/current-config" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <V8Exch:Data>
        <v8:ConstantValueManager.ИспользоватьДокументыПоступления>
            <v8:Value>true</v8:Value>
        </v8:ConstantValueManager.ИспользоватьДокументыПоступления>
        <v8:CatalogObject.Номенклатура>
            <v8:IsFolder>true</v8:IsFolder>
            <v8:Ref xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Номенклатура">1dccc9cc-3823-11ec-bb94-000000000003</v8:Ref>
            <v8:DeletionMark>false</v8:DeletionMark>
            <v8:Parent xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Номенклатура">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:Parent>
            <v8:Code>00-00000001</v8:Code>
            <v8:Description>Товары</v8:Description>
            <v8:ВидНоменклатуры xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.ВидыНоменклатуры">bc83a171-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:ВидНоменклатуры>
        </v8:CatalogObject.Номенклатура>
        <v8:CatalogObject.Номенклатура>
            <v8:IsFolder>false</v8:IsFolder>
            <v8:Ref xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Номенклатура">ab0cdab9-38e9-11ec-bb95-000000000003</v8:Ref>
            <v8:DeletionMark>false</v8:DeletionMark>
            <v8:Parent xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Номенклатура">1dccc9cc-3823-11ec-bb94-000000000003</v8:Parent>
            <v8:Code>00-00000002</v8:Code>
            <v8:Description>Апельсин</v8:Description>
            <v8:Артикул>001</v8:Артикул>
            <v8:ВидНоменклатуры xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.ВидыНоменклатуры">bc83a171-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:ВидНоменклатуры>
            <v8:ЕдиницаИзмерения xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.КлассификаторЕдиницИзмерения">bc83a16f-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:ЕдиницаИзмерения>
            <v8:НаименованиеПолное>Апельсин</v8:НаименованиеПолное>
            <v8:Комментарий/>
            <v8:Услуга>false</v8:Услуга>
            <v8:НоменклатурнаяГруппа xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.НоменклатурныеГруппы">bc83a170-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:НоменклатурнаяГруппа>
            <v8:СтранаПроисхождения xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.СтраныМира">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:СтранаПроисхождения>
            <v8:СтатьяЗатрат xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.СтатьиЗатрат">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:СтатьяЗатрат>
            <v8:НомерГТД xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.НомераГТД">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:НомерГТД>
            <v8:ОсновнаяСпецификацияНоменклатуры xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.СпецификацииНоменклатуры">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:ОсновнаяСпецификацияНоменклатуры>
            <v8:Производитель xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Контрагенты">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:Производитель>
            <v8:Импортер xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Контрагенты">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:Импортер>
            <v8:КодТНВЭД xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.КлассификаторТНВЭД">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:КодТНВЭД>
            <v8:КодОКВЭД2 xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.КлассификаторОКВЭД2">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:КодОКВЭД2>
            <v8:КодОКВЭД xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.КлассификаторВидовЭкономическойДеятельности">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:КодОКВЭД>
            <v8:КодОКП xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.ОбщероссийскийКлассификаторПродукции">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:КодОКП>
            <v8:КодОКПД2 xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.КлассификаторОКПД2">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:КодОКПД2>
            <v8:УдалитьСтавкаНДС/>
            <v8:ПродукцияМаркируемаяДляГИСМ>false</v8:ПродукцияМаркируемаяДляГИСМ>
            <v8:ПериодичностьУслуги/>
            <v8:КодРаздел7ДекларацииНДС xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.КодыОперацийРаздела7ДекларацииПоНДС">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:КодРаздел7ДекларацииНДС>
            <v8:ПодконтрольнаяПродукцияВЕТИС>false</v8:ПодконтрольнаяПродукцияВЕТИС>
            <v8:ВидСтавкиНДС>Общая</v8:ВидСтавкиНДС>
            <v8:ТабачнаяПродукция>false</v8:ТабачнаяПродукция>
            <v8:ОбувнаяПродукция>false</v8:ОбувнаяПродукция>
        </v8:CatalogObject.Номенклатура>
        <v8:CatalogObject.Номенклатура>
            <v8:IsFolder>false</v8:IsFolder>
            <v8:Ref xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Номенклатура">b7b246d9-38ea-11ec-bb95-000000000003</v8:Ref>
            <v8:DeletionMark>false</v8:DeletionMark>
            <v8:Parent xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Номенклатура">1dccc9cc-3823-11ec-bb94-000000000003</v8:Parent>
            <v8:Code>00-00000003</v8:Code>
            <v8:Description>Помидор</v8:Description>
            <v8:Артикул>002</v8:Артикул>
            <v8:ВидНоменклатуры xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.ВидыНоменклатуры">bc83a171-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:ВидНоменклатуры>
            <v8:ЕдиницаИзмерения xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.КлассификаторЕдиницИзмерения">bc83a16e-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:ЕдиницаИзмерения>
            <v8:НаименованиеПолное>Помидор</v8:НаименованиеПолное>
            <v8:Комментарий/>
            <v8:Услуга>false</v8:Услуга>
            <v8:НоменклатурнаяГруппа xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.НоменклатурныеГруппы">bc83a170-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:НоменклатурнаяГруппа>
            <v8:СтранаПроисхождения xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.СтраныМира">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:СтранаПроисхождения>
            <v8:НомерГТД xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.НомераГТД">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:НомерГТД>
            <v8:СтатьяЗатрат xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.СтатьиЗатрат">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:СтатьяЗатрат>
            <v8:ОсновнаяСпецификацияНоменклатуры xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.СпецификацииНоменклатуры">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:ОсновнаяСпецификацияНоменклатуры>
            <v8:Производитель xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Контрагенты">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:Производитель>
            <v8:Импортер xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Контрагенты">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:Импортер>
            <v8:КодТНВЭД xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.КлассификаторТНВЭД">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:КодТНВЭД>
            <v8:КодОКВЭД2 xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.КлассификаторОКВЭД2">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:КодОКВЭД2>
            <v8:КодОКВЭД xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.КлассификаторВидовЭкономическойДеятельности">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:КодОКВЭД>
            <v8:КодОКП xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.ОбщероссийскийКлассификаторПродукции">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:КодОКП>
            <v8:КодОКПД2 xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.КлассификаторОКПД2">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:КодОКПД2>
            <v8:УдалитьСтавкаНДС/>
            <v8:ПродукцияМаркируемаяДляГИСМ>false</v8:ПродукцияМаркируемаяДляГИСМ>
            <v8:ПериодичностьУслуги/>
            <v8:КодРаздел7ДекларацииНДС xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.КодыОперацийРаздела7ДекларацииПоНДС">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:КодРаздел7ДекларацииНДС>
            <v8:ПодконтрольнаяПродукцияВЕТИС>false</v8:ПодконтрольнаяПродукцияВЕТИС>
            <v8:ВидСтавкиНДС>Общая</v8:ВидСтавкиНДС>
            <v8:ТабачнаяПродукция>false</v8:ТабачнаяПродукция>
            <v8:ОбувнаяПродукция>false</v8:ОбувнаяПродукция>
        </v8:CatalogObject.Номенклатура>
        <v8:DocumentObject.РеализацияТоваровУслуг>
            <v8:Ref>ab0cdaba-38e9-11ec-bb95-000000000003</v8:Ref>
            <v8:DeletionMark>false</v8:DeletionMark>
            <v8:Date>2021-10-29T23:59:59</v8:Date>
            <v8:Number>0000-000001</v8:Number>
            <v8:Posted>true</v8:Posted>
            <v8:ВидОперации>Товары</v8:ВидОперации>
            <v8:Организация xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Организации">12bb3b0b-3823-11ec-bb94-000000000003</v8:Организация>
            <v8:Склад xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Склады">bc83a16d-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:Склад>
            <v8:ПодразделениеОрганизации xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.ПодразделенияОрганизаций">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:ПодразделениеОрганизации>
            <v8:ДеятельностьНаПатенте>false</v8:ДеятельностьНаПатенте>
            <v8:Патент xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Патенты">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:Патент>
            <v8:Контрагент xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Контрагенты">ab0cdab6-38e9-11ec-bb95-000000000003</v8:Контрагент>
            <v8:ДоговорКонтрагента xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.ДоговорыКонтрагентов">ab0cdab7-38e9-11ec-bb95-000000000003</v8:ДоговорКонтрагента>
            <v8:СпособЗачетаАвансов>Автоматически</v8:СпособЗачетаАвансов>
            <v8:ТипЦен xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.ТипыЦенНоменклатуры">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:ТипЦен>
            <v8:ВалютаДокумента xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Валюты">6f5dc185-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:ВалютаДокумента>
            <v8:КурсВзаиморасчетов>1</v8:КурсВзаиморасчетов>
            <v8:КратностьВзаиморасчетов>1</v8:КратностьВзаиморасчетов>
            <v8:СуммаВключаетНДС>true</v8:СуммаВключаетНДС>
            <v8:УдалитьУчитыватьНДС>false</v8:УдалитьУчитыватьНДС>
            <v8:СчетУчетаРасчетовСКонтрагентом xsi:type="v8:ChartOfAccountsRef.Хозрасчетный">5b1488ff-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:СчетУчетаРасчетовСКонтрагентом>
            <v8:СчетУчетаРасчетовПоАвансам xsi:type="v8:ChartOfAccountsRef.Хозрасчетный">5b148900-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:СчетУчетаРасчетовПоАвансам>
            <v8:СчетУчетаРасчетовПоТаре xsi:type="v8:ChartOfAccountsRef.Хозрасчетный">5b148969-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:СчетУчетаРасчетовПоТаре>
            <v8:УдалитьСчетУчетаДоходовПоТаре xsi:type="v8:ChartOfAccountsRef.Хозрасчетный">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:УдалитьСчетУчетаДоходовПоТаре>
            <v8:УдалитьСчетУчетаРасходовПоТаре xsi:type="v8:ChartOfAccountsRef.Хозрасчетный">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:УдалитьСчетУчетаРасходовПоТаре>
            <v8:УдалитьСтатьяДоходовИРасходовПоТаре xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.ПрочиеДоходыИРасходы">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:УдалитьСтатьяДоходовИРасходовПоТаре>
            <v8:СчетНаОплатуПокупателю>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:СчетНаОплатуПокупателю>
            <v8:Грузоотправитель xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Контрагенты">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:Грузоотправитель>
            <v8:Грузополучатель xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Контрагенты">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:Грузополучатель>
            <v8:АдресДоставки/>
            <v8:БанковскийСчетОрганизации xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.БанковскиеСчета">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:БанковскийСчетОрганизации>
            <v8:СуммаДокумента>271</v8:СуммаДокумента>
            <v8:Ответственный xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Пользователи">aa00559e-ad84-4494-88fd-f0826edc46f0</v8:Ответственный>
            <v8:Комментарий/>
            <v8:РучнаяКорректировка>false</v8:РучнаяКорректировка>
            <v8:Руководитель xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.ФизическиеЛица">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:Руководитель>
            <v8:ГлавныйБухгалтер xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.ФизическиеЛица">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:ГлавныйБухгалтер>
            <v8:ОтпускПроизвел xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.ФизическиеЛица">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:ОтпускПроизвел>
            <v8:УдалитьЗаРуководителяПоПриказу/>
            <v8:УдалитьЗаГлавногоБухгалтераПоПриказу/>
            <v8:ЗаЗаказчикаНаОсновании/>
            <v8:ДоверенностьНомер/>
            <v8:ДоверенностьДата>0001-01-01T00:00:00</v8:ДоверенностьДата>
            <v8:ДоверенностьВыдана/>
            <v8:ДоверенностьЧерезКого/>
            <v8:ВидЭлектронногоДокумента>ТОРГ12Продавец</v8:ВидЭлектронногоДокумента>
            <v8:ДокументБезНДС>true</v8:ДокументБезНДС>
            <v8:ЗаРуководителяНаОсновании xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.ОснованияПраваПодписи">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:ЗаРуководителяНаОсновании>
            <v8:ЗаГлавногоБухгалтераНаОсновании xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.ОснованияПраваПодписи">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:ЗаГлавногоБухгалтераНаОсновании>
            <v8:Перевозчик xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Контрагенты">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:Перевозчик>
            <v8:МаркаАвтомобиля/>
            <v8:РегистрационныйЗнакАвтомобиля/>
            <v8:Водитель/>
            <v8:ВодительскоеУдостоверение/>
            <v8:КраткоеНаименованиеГруза/>
            <v8:СопроводительныеДокументы/>
            <v8:ДеятельностьНаТорговомСборе>false</v8:ДеятельностьНаТорговомСборе>
            <v8:ОтветственныйЗаОформление xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.ФизическиеЛица">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:ОтветственныйЗаОформление>
            <v8:СведенияОТранспортировкеИГрузе/>
            <v8:ПеревозкаАвтотранспортом>false</v8:ПеревозкаАвтотранспортом>
            <v8:ЕстьМаркируемаяПродукцияГИСМ>false</v8:ЕстьМаркируемаяПродукцияГИСМ>
            <v8:НомерЧекаККМ>0</v8:НомерЧекаККМ>
            <v8:Товары>
                <v8:Номенклатура xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Номенклатура">ab0cdab9-38e9-11ec-bb95-000000000003</v8:Номенклатура>
                <v8:КоличествоМест>0</v8:КоличествоМест>
                <v8:ЕдиницаИзмерения xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.КлассификаторЕдиницИзмерения">bc83a16f-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:ЕдиницаИзмерения>
                <v8:Коэффициент>1</v8:Коэффициент>
                <v8:Количество>10</v8:Количество>
                <v8:Цена>5</v8:Цена>
                <v8:Сумма>50</v8:Сумма>
                <v8:СтавкаНДС>БезНДС</v8:СтавкаНДС>
                <v8:СуммаНДС>0</v8:СуммаНДС>
                <v8:СчетУчета xsi:type="v8:ChartOfAccountsRef.Хозрасчетный">5b1488c2-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:СчетУчета>
                <v8:ПереданныеСчетУчета xsi:type="v8:ChartOfAccountsRef.Хозрасчетный">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:ПереданныеСчетУчета>
                <v8:СчетДоходов xsi:type="v8:ChartOfAccountsRef.Хозрасчетный">5b1489ac-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:СчетДоходов>
                <v8:Субконто xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.НоменклатурныеГруппы">bc83a170-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:Субконто>
                <v8:СчетУчетаНДСПоРеализации xsi:type="v8:ChartOfAccountsRef.Хозрасчетный">5b1489b1-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:СчетУчетаНДСПоРеализации>
                <v8:СчетРасходов xsi:type="v8:ChartOfAccountsRef.Хозрасчетный">5b1489af-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:СчетРасходов>
                <v8:ДокументОприходования xsi:nil="true"/>
                <v8:Себестоимость>0</v8:Себестоимость>
                <v8:НомерГТД xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.НомераГТД">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:НомерГТД>
                <v8:СтранаПроисхождения xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.СтраныМира">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:СтранаПроисхождения>
                <v8:КиЗ_ГИСМ xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.КонтрольныеЗнакиГИСМ">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:КиЗ_ГИСМ>
                <v8:КодТНВЭД xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.КлассификаторТНВЭД">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:КодТНВЭД>
            </v8:Товары>
            <v8:Товары>
                <v8:Номенклатура xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Номенклатура">b7b246d9-38ea-11ec-bb95-000000000003</v8:Номенклатура>
                <v8:КоличествоМест>0</v8:КоличествоМест>
                <v8:ЕдиницаИзмерения xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.КлассификаторЕдиницИзмерения">bc83a16e-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:ЕдиницаИзмерения>
                <v8:Коэффициент>1</v8:Коэффициент>
                <v8:Количество>17</v8:Количество>
                <v8:Цена>13</v8:Цена>
                <v8:Сумма>221</v8:Сумма>
                <v8:СтавкаНДС>БезНДС</v8:СтавкаНДС>
                <v8:СуммаНДС>0</v8:СуммаНДС>
                <v8:СчетУчета xsi:type="v8:ChartOfAccountsRef.Хозрасчетный">5b1488c2-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:СчетУчета>
                <v8:ПереданныеСчетУчета xsi:type="v8:ChartOfAccountsRef.Хозрасчетный">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:ПереданныеСчетУчета>
                <v8:СчетДоходов xsi:type="v8:ChartOfAccountsRef.Хозрасчетный">5b1489ac-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:СчетДоходов>
                <v8:Субконто xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.НоменклатурныеГруппы">bc83a170-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:Субконто>
                <v8:СчетУчетаНДСПоРеализации xsi:type="v8:ChartOfAccountsRef.Хозрасчетный">5b1489b1-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:СчетУчетаНДСПоРеализации>
                <v8:СчетРасходов xsi:type="v8:ChartOfAccountsRef.Хозрасчетный">5b1489af-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:СчетРасходов>
                <v8:ДокументОприходования xsi:nil="true"/>
                <v8:Себестоимость>0</v8:Себестоимость>
                <v8:НомерГТД xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.НомераГТД">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:НомерГТД>
                <v8:СтранаПроисхождения xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.СтраныМира">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:СтранаПроисхождения>
                <v8:КиЗ_ГИСМ xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.КонтрольныеЗнакиГИСМ">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:КиЗ_ГИСМ>
                <v8:КодТНВЭД xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.КлассификаторТНВЭД">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:КодТНВЭД>
            </v8:Товары>
        </v8:DocumentObject.РеализацияТоваровУслуг>
    </V8Exch:Data>
    <PredefinedData/>
</V8Exch:_1CV8DtUD>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("2.xml", null, 0, 'V8Exch', true);
$data = $xml->Data->children('v8', true);

foreach (get_object_vars($data)['CatalogObject.Номенклатура'] as $dat) {
    var_dump($dat->НаименованиеПолное);
}
?>
```

Comment: Сделал немного проще: $title = $xml->xpath('//v8:НаименованиеПолное');
foreach($title as $products){
 echo "$products<br>";
}
?>